# Is there a shorthand version for posting links to other questions in a comment?

Tags: feature-request, editing

I read the [comment formatting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) help and there are several shorthand links available to refer to pages within the SE network.

Quite often I post links to related questions in a comment and this turns out to be rather ugly. See the [comments on this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16377/where-and-how-to-obtain-buy-good-looking-2d-art-sets) as an example.

Is there a shorthand version to link to a specific question within the same site? Eg. something like `[#15256]` to insert a link to the question with the given ID? It would be nice if the system would replace that shorthand link with the title of the question and an actual link to it :)

Or maybe the pasted URLs could be parsed and replaced with the actual Title of the question?

Is such a thing already in place? I was under the impression that something like this was already implemented at some point.

Comment: I didn't know that shorthand existed, so that's awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Link Text]
(Actual Link) to format links in comments.

Comment: Yes I know. But it would be nice to have a shortcut for questions within the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the text from the URL at least. So a link to this question, instead of:

`http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/575/is-there-a-shorthand-version-for-posting-links-to-other-questions-in-a-comment`

would be:

`http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/575/`

Doesn't make it much prettier, but you can use the saved space to make a title for the link.

Comment: You can also cut that 'questions' down to a 'q'. The 'share' link will provide you with such a URL. Here's a link to this question with my referral code snipped off the end to demonstrate it still works: [http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/575](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/575). A link to this answer: [http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/964](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/964)